# Android Retrofit post request not working

Tags: android, retrofit

i have posted my retrofit code below where there is an interface and a mainactivity method where the method on a response body just receves an 
 tag unlike any data and also the data into database is not inserted .. trying using xammp

Here in interface i have defined keys

> unable to send post request using retrofit android
>   here is my interface and mainactivity class given below
>   my interface

```
    public interface RegisterApi {
    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("/myfolder/services.php?module=jobs&action=post_new_jobs")
    void insertUser(
            @Field("posted_by") String posted_by,
            @Field("company_name") String company_name,
            @Field("position") String position,
            @Field("eligiblity") String eligiblity,
            @Field("experience") String experience,
            @Field("interview_from_date") String interview_from_date,
            @Field("interview_to_date") String interview_to_date,
            @Field("interview_frm_timing") String interview_frm_timing,
            @Field("interview_to_timing") String    interview_to_timing,
            @Field("describtion") String describtion,
            @Field("skills") String skills,
            @Field("interview_location") String interview_location,
            @Field("interview_lat") String  interview_lat,
            @Field("interview_lon") String interview_lon,
            @Field("contact_person") String contact_person,
            @Field("contact_email") String contact_email,
            @Field("contact_phone") String  contact_phone,
            @Field("total_vocancies") String total_vocancies,
            Callback<Response> callback);
}
```

Here this method is called on final button click to make a post request but unfortunately i get  in the response msg

> Mainactivity

```
 private void insertUser() {
        //Here we will handle the http request to insert user to mysql db
        //Creating a RestAdapter
        RestAdapter adapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
                .setEndpoint(AllConstants.MAIN_URL) //Setting the Root URL
                .build(); //Finally building the adapter

        //Creating object for our interface
        RegisterApi api = adapter.create(RegisterApi.class);

        //Defining the method insertuser of our interface
        api.insertUser(

                AllConstants.USER_ID,
                companyName.getText().toString(),
                position.getText().toString(),
                eligiblity.getText().toString(),
                experience.getText().toString(),
                interviewFrmDate.getText().toString(),
                interviewToDate.getText().toString(),
                interviewFromTime.getText().toString(),
                interviewToTime.getText().toString(),
                desc.getText().toString(),
                skillsRequired.getText().toString(),
                interviewLocation.getText().toString(),
                String.valueOf(lat),
                String.valueOf(lon),
                contactperson.getText().toString(),
                contactMail.getText().toString(),
                contactPhone.getText().toString(),
                totalVocancies.getText().toString(),

                //Passing the values by getting it from editTexts

                //Creating an anonymous callback
                new Callback<Response>() {
                    @Override
                    public void success(Response result, Response response) {
                        //On success we will read the server's output using bufferedreader
                        //Creating a bufferedreader object
                        BufferedReader reader = null;

                        //An string to store output from the server
                        String output = "";

                        try {
                            //Initializing buffered reader
                            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(result.getBody().in()));
                            //Reading the output in the string
                            output = reader.readLine();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            System.out.println("###coming exception");
                        }

                        //Displaying the output as a toast
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, output, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        System.out.println("###coming output" + response.toString());
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
                        //If any error occured displaying the error as toast
                        System.out.println("###coming failure" + error.toString());
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
        );
    }
```

Comment: this is how i did but still its not working ...

Comment: void insertUser(
            @Query("module") String module,
            @Query("action") String action,

Answer (score 0):

You should pass arguments from ?module=jobs&action=post_new_jobs" as method arguments with @Query annotation:

@POST("/myfolder/services.php")
    void insertUser(
            @Field("posted_by") String posted_by,
    @Query("module") String module name, 
    @Query("action") String action)

Comment: instead of  module=jobs&action=post_new_jobs pass it in method, at least I do it in that way